# OnTouch not running when touched

Tags: java, android

I'm not getting any errors when I run my code, but nothing happens I touch the screen. The value of the global variable select should change but nothing happens.

Here is the code

```
public class NonmultiplierSixGame extends AppCompatActivity {   
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_nonmultiplier_six_game);
  }
}
```

activity_nonmultiplier_six_game:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.alexandermain.example_5.NonmultiplierSixGame">





    <com.example.alexandermain.example_5.views.NonmultiplierSixView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nonmultiplierSixView"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

NonmultiplierSixView class:

```
public class NonmultiplierSixView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
//bunch of shapes
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Globals.SetSelect(1);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Globals.SetSelect(2);
            break;

    }

    return true;
}



public NonmultiplierSixView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
}
```

Edit:
Here is the Globals class
public class Globals {

```
public static int select=-2;
public static void SetSelect(int t) {
    select = t;
}
public static int GetSelect() {
    return(select);
}
```

}

Comment: mention the Globals.SetSelect function here

Comment: with Globals class

Comment: I edited the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement OntouchListener, you need to setThe listener on your Context.

Simply add it in your constructor:
It should be like this:

```
public NonmultiplierSixView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I had to do this. However it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The onDraw method repeats conitnuously.
So maybe, even if you touch your object, it is everytime redrawn to its initial position because of the onDraw.
So what you wanna do is for example set a boolean isPostionned, so your object will be drawn on initial position only 1 time.
so the boolean will be initially false, and then you set it true once your item is drawn.


For example: declare in your NonmultiplierSixView class

boolean isPositionned = false;

than in onDraw:

if (!isPositionned){
   //code to position you object
   isPositionned = true;
    }

Comment: Apparently, OnTouch is working its something with Globals that isn't. When I had it print something to the log it works when I click it. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a pretty inexperienced programmer but I created onTouch listener earlier today which works fine,

Try to change the onTouch method to something like this:

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Globals.SetSelect(1);
                    return false;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Globals.SetSelect(2);
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I'm sorry in advance if it doesn't work for you..

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to implements `View.OnTouchListener`, **View class already have its `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method** . Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                           break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                           break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                           break;
            }
           return true;
       }
```

It will definately work. and check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) also.

Comment: Thanks you! I tried this, and while I didn't get any errors, nothing happens when I click on the screen. Any other ideas of what the problem could be?

Comment: Wondered  why it was not working , may be because we are returning false(as per Android Docs  " return True if the event was handled, false otherwise.") i have updated the code check it

Comment: Could you explain what you mean in the last comment. I'm very new to android studio. How do I put a log in each condition and debug it?

Comment: it was misplayed "I have done  lot of work in Gaming, we normally use custom Views and its onTouchEvent() methods for handle user touch, please print Log there in each condition check either its printing somthing in Log or not"

Comment: Apparently, OnTouch is working. its something with Global that isn't. When I had it print something to the log it works when I click it. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The onDraw method repeats continuously.
So maybe, even if you touch your object, it is everytime redrawn to its initial position because of the onDraw.
So what you wanna do is for example set a boolean isPostionned, so your object will be drawn on initial position only 1 time.
so the boolean will be initially false, and then you set it true once your item is drawn.

For example: declare in your NonmultiplierSixView class

```
boolean isPositionned = false;
```

than in onDraw:

```
if (!isPositionned){
   //code to position you object
   isPositionned = true;
    }
```

(This is in case your intention is to move the shape)